Debian NAT Gateway with dnsmasq DHCP, reachable via internal IP
I have setup a Debian 12 machine as an IPv4 NAT Gateway / Router by following the various tutorials on the internet (mostly following arch wiki) and tried to do it the most modern way possible.
I use dnsmasq as a DHCP and DNS Server to provide IPs on the internal network.
For firewalling / NAT Masquerading I use nftables.
This works as intended.
BUT, I have a strange problem I can't explain:
my gateway computer is reachable via its internal IP 10.0.0.1 from the outside, which shouldn't be possible.
the arp tables of outside computers show the gateways' external interface MAC for this IP?
? (10.0.0.1) at 00:30:18:11:5e:b6 [ether] on ens32
how is this possible?
did I make a configuration mistake?
what can I do to examine why this is happening?

here is my configuration:
IP config, static:
enp3s0: 00:30:18:11:5e:b6, 192.168.0.15/20 (external, corporate network)
enp7s0: 00:30:18:11:5e:b7, 10.0.0.1/23 (internal, lab network)
sysctl:
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
nftables.conf:
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

# block all except corporate network
# the gateway computer is excluded, we only block devices within the lab network...
table inet filter{ #inet: ip + ip6
  chain forward {
    type filter hook forward priority 0; # 0 == filter, since 0.9.3
    policy drop;

    # allow connections that originated from us ( == answers)
    ct state established,related accept;

    # drop everything for specific hosts
    #ip saddr client1 drop;

    # allow destination: corporate network
    ip daddr 192.168.0.0/20 accept;

    # allow everything for specific hosts
    #ip saddr client1 accept;

  }
}

# NAT MASQUERADE RULES
table ip nat {
  chain mask {
    # priority 100 == srcnat, srcnat only since 0.9.3
    type nat hook postrouting priority 100;
    oifname "enp3s0" masquerade
  }
}

dnsmasq.conf:
bogus-priv
domain-needed

listen-address=::1,127.0.0.1,10.0.0.1

interface=enp7s0

expand-hosts

local=/lab.lan/
domain=lab.lan

no-resolv
server=192.168.1.1 # corporates' DNS server

host-record=lab.lan,10.0.0.1

read-ethers

dhcp-range=10.0.0.10,10.0.0.50,255.255.254.0,24h

dhcp-option=option:domain-search,lab.lan,corporate.net.de,corp.net.de,corp.de

I replaced the real corporates' IPs and domain names with fictional ones.
Shouldn't matter here ...


my gateway computer is reachable via its internal IP 10.0.0.1 from the outside, which shouldn't be possible

That is expected behavior, assuming that systems on the external side have a route to 10.0.0.0/24 that includes the external network. Consider a configuration like this:
                                   10.0.0.1    
                                      │        
                                      │        
                                      │        
  ┌────────┐                ┌───────┐ │        
  │        │                │       │ ▼        
  │ host1  │eth0────────eth0│ host2 │eth1────  
  │        │ ▲           ▲  │       │          
  └────────┘ │           │  └───────┘          
             │           │                     
             │           │                     
             │           │                     
       100.64.64.1     100.64.64.10            
                                               

If host1 has a route that looks like 10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0, then when someone runs, say, ping 10.0.0.1:

host1 sends out an ARP request over eth0 that says, "Hey, who has address 10.0.0.1?".
host2 sees the ARP request, recognizes that it is a request for a locally configured address, and sends an ARP reply that says, "Me! I have address 10.0.0.1!"
From now on, host1 will send traffic to 10.0.0.1, via eth0, directed to the MAC address of eth0 on host2.

If you don't this to happen, add firewall rules on host2 that prohibit traffic to 10.0.0.1 on any interface other than eth1. Using iptables, that might look like:
iptables -A INPUT -d 10.0.0.1 ! -i eth1 -j DROP


Thank you for your answer.
So you say, that happens as soon as I enable IP Forwarding?
I thought about that earlier, but wasn't sure if thats really the cause.

Another thought on that:
Why would my machine make an ARP Request in the first place? 10.0.0.1 is not in the same subnet as itself is, so shouldn't it omit any ARP stuff and send the Packet directly to the default route, i.e. my router?
I think this is actually the case, because if I do a traceroute, I always get a hop over the router first.

Your machine isn't the one making an ARP request. I am just explaining how a machine on the outside network would be able to access your machine using it's internal ip address. This has nothing to do with ip forwarding. This is just basic routing behavior. (Adding for clarification: in the diagram, "your" machine is host2).
